# texture view is not working with mediacodec for decoding below api 21

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android-mediacodec

The following code is working with API 21 and above. However, when I run it on below 21, no data shows up on TextureView.

My configuration for MediaCodec:

```
MediaFormat format =    MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC, 1920, 1080);

        format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", ByteBuffer.allocate(100));

        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE, 100000);
        try {

            m_codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC);

            m_codec.configure(format, new Surface(m_surface.getSurfaceTexture()), null, 0);

            m_codec.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The decoding part:

```
int inputIndex = m_codec.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);

            if (inputIndex >= 0) {
                ByteBuffer buffer;
                MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    buffer = m_codec.getInputBuffer(inputIndex);
                    buffer.clear();
                }
                else {
                    buffer=m_codec.getInputBuffers()[inputIndex];
                    buffer.put(videoBuffer,0,info.size);
                }
                if (buffer != null) {
                    buffer.put(videoBuffer, info.offset,videoBuffer.length);
                    m_codec.queueInputBuffer(inputIndex, 0, videoBuffer.length, 0, 0);
                }

            }

            MediaCodec.BufferInfo info = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
            int outputIndex = m_codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(info, 0);

            if (outputIndex >= 0) {
                m_codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outputIndex, true);
            }
```

## EDIT:

I got the solution,when i removed below line, now it's working

```
format.setByteBuffer("csd-0", ByteBuffer.allocate(100));
```